# Summing values using an adjacency matrix in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, df1 (10x2) containing 10 zipcodes and the total number of PV installations in per zipcode, and df2, which is a matrix 10x10 matrix, indicating which zipcodes are neighbouring, indicated by 1/0.

Dataframe 1

| zipcode | PV |
| --- | --- |
| 5095 | 19 |
| 5999 | 29 |
| 3434 | 1 |

Dataframe 2

| 5095 | 5999 | 3434 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |

As dataframe 2 shows, zipcode 5095 is neighbouring 5999, zipcode 5999 is neighbouring both 5095 and 3434, and zipcode 3434 is neighbouring 5999.

The goal is to calculate the **number of PV installations in areas surrounding each zipcode.**
So for zipcode 5095, this value needs to be 29, for zipcode 5999 it needs to be 20 and for zipcode 3434 the answer is 29.

How can I do this?

Comment: I _think_ your frame2 is (or should be) a matrix instead of a frame with no row names, but if it is, is it safe to assume that it is always square and that row "names" always correspond to column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply `df2` by `df1$PV` element-wise and sum the columns:

```
df1 <- data.frame(zipcode = c(5095, 5999, 3434), PV = c(19, 29, 1))
df2 <- matrix(rep(0:1, length.out = 9), 3, 3)
setNames(colSums(df2*df1$PV), df1$zipcode)
#> 5095 5999 3434 
#>   29   20   29
```

No need for `setNames` if `df2` is named.

```
df2 <- matrix(rep(0:1, length.out = 9), 3, 3, 0, rep(list(df1$zipcode), 2))
colSums(df2*df1$PV)
#> 5095 5999 3434 
#>   29   20   29
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the order of columns in the second data frame is the same as the rows of zipcodes in the first data frame, and that the second data frame is square, one solution is:

```r
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~zipcode, ~PV,
5095,   19,
5999,   29,
3434,   1)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~`5095`,  ~`5999`,    ~`3434`,
  0,    1,  0,
  1,    0,  1,
  0,    1,  0,
)

sapply(as.character(df1$zipcode), function(x) sum(df2[[x]] * df1$PV))
```

which gives:

```r
5095 5999 3434 
  29   20   29
```